# Could not find implicit Marshaller in Spray.io when using Jackson

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, jerkson

I have a Spray.io directive that handles a POST and I want to use Jerkson (scala interface for Jackson) to parse the incoming JSON into the appropriate class.

```
post {
        path("") {
          entity(as[String]) { stuff =>
              complete {
                parse[User](stuff)
              }
          }
        }
      }
```

The issue is that when I go to compile, Spray goes looking for a Marshaller:

```
    [error] C:\project\src\main\scala\com\project\AccountService\controllers\Users.scala:53: 
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
 spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[com.project.AccountService.models.User]
    [error]                     parse[User](stuff)
    [error]                                ^
    [error] one error found
```

Do I need to write a custom Marhsaller for this? Or is my directive not written properly? And if I do need one, any good examples out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This managed to get the job done:

```
post {
        path("") {
          entity(as[String]) { body =>
            val user = parse[User](body)
                    complete(generate(user))
          }
        }
      }
```

Looks like since I wasn't returning a string in the `complete` it started looking for a Marshaller to Marshall my User object.